# How to set application library in virtual host with IfModule mod_php5.c in Xampp windows

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

I am working on multiple zend project. All project have different version of zend framework library.some have 1.12.3 and some have 1.12.11. I have create virtual host on linux server for all projects and add zend library with IfModule mod_php5 in virtual host configuration project wise.This is working fine in lunux server but I want to do same for xampp in windows I set same configuration in virtual host in xampp but my application can't get library.

**Linux configuration:**

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_value include_path ".:/usr/local/zend/var/libraries/Zend_Framework_1/default/library:"
</IfModule>
<Directory "/data/Application/project1/Webapps/public">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
DocumentRoot /data/Application/project1/Webapps/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Above configuration working fine in linux server./usr/local/zend/var/libraries/Zend_Framework_1/default/library this is my zend library path from where project load library file.Now I want to same in xampp

**Xampp Configuration window**

```
<VirtualHost project1.com>
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_value include_path ".:D:/projects/Zend-1.12.3"
</IfModule>
    DocumentRoot "D:\project1/Webapps/public"
    <Directory "D:project1/Webapps/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ServerName project1.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Above configuration zend library is not loaded.Anyone have solution for it?